# Why this bash string concatenation fails?

Tags: string, bash, concatenation

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR_A=100
VAR_B=200

FOO="$VAR_A_$VAR_B"; # 200
BAZ="$VAR_Ax$VAR_B"; # 200

echo $FOO; # 200 instead of 100_200
echo $BAZ; # 200 instead of 100x200
```

The reason why I think it should work is that I look at it as it would be sprinf or any C-like string formatter(%s_%s or %sx%s)

Comment: `bash` can't figure out what the variable names are.  Try `${VAR_A}_${VAR_B}`.

Comment: Also get into the habit of  quoting your variables when you use them: `echo "$FOO"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `_` is a valid character in a variable name. To distinguish this, use braces:

```
FOO="${VAR_A}_$VAR_B"
```

For consistency, you could use braces everywhere:

```
FOO="${VAR_A}_${VAR_B}"
```